# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: angular, laravel

working with Angular and Laravel API. in my Angular I have routerLink on My student.component.html

```
<a routerLink="employee/{{emp.id}}"><td> {{emp.first_name}}</td></a>
```

I have import routerLink as well in app.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRouters),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

but I got following error message with the link `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.ngtsc(-998002) employees.component.ts(8, 20): Error occurs in the template of component StudentComponent.`
how to fix this?

Comment: You show the source code of `student.component.html`, but the error occurs in the file `employees.component.ts` on line 8. It would be more helpful to post that file too.

Comment: As any another "Directive" (routerLink) that belong to a Module (RouterModule), you can only use it in a Component (student.component) if this component are declared in a Module (I imagine your component student.component is declared in a module student.module) and this module have in the array "imports" this module (RouterModule) -not only in app.module-

Comment: See how in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vshpsk?file=src%2Fstudent%2Fstudent.module.ts) the RouterModule are in the array "imports" of the app.Module and in the array imports of the module student.module

Comment: @mahalde yes I edited the question